# How do I prove the subadditivity of the limit superior for sequences?

Tags: real-analysis

I've been struggling for a while to prove this theorem:

$\limsup s_n + t_n \leq \limsup s_n + \limsup t_n$ for bounded sequences $(s_n)$ and $(t_n)$

The textbook says it's easy to prove the above theorem by first showing:

$\sup \{s_n + t_n \, : \, n > N\} \leq \sup \{s_n \, : \, n > N\} + \sup \{t_n \, : \, n > N\}$ for some integer $N$

but these seem like basically equivalent theorems to me, since the first is just the limit as $N$ goes to $\infty$ of the second right? I've already looked at a few similar threads on Math StackExchange but those weren't really helpful. I'd really appreciate any suggestions/pointers on what to do here. Thanks!

Comment: You just said how the claim would follow from that inequality. So, prove that inequality.

Comment: You should probably do something to ensure you don't just get a repeat of the threads you have already seen, e.g. linking to the threads you have checked, and pointing out what you don't like about them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for returning to this so late! I went to office hours and wrote this solution from what my professor said:

For each $N$, $s_N \leq \sup \{s_n \, : \, n \geq N\} = S_N$ and $t_N \leq \sup \{t_n \, : \, n \geq N\} = T_N$ by the definition of the supremum. Adding these inequalities together, we get that $s_N + t_N \leq S_N + T_N$. Since the inequality holds for all $N$ and $S_N + T_N$ can only decrease as $N$ increases, every term $s_n + t_n \leq S_N + T_N$ for $n > N$, and therefore $\sup \{s_n + t_n \, : \, n \geq N\} \leq S_N + T_N$. We take the limit of this expression as $N$ goes to $\infty$ (which exists since $(s_n)$ and $(t_n)$ are both bounded) to obtain $\limsup s_n + t_n \leq \limsup s_n + \limsup t_n$.

Hope this helps!